# Random number generation: changing time interval

Tags: probability, random

I'm interested in generating random numbers.

I have a distribution [for simplicity let it be uniform distribution] of some event occurrence, i.e. the event occurs between $1$ to $3$ times per year.

I know how to generate the distribution per year [at least c++ gives me this ability].

My question is

> how should i generate the distribution of events per month?

I thought, that if I had let say $1$ event per year, then I could generate a real number from $0$ to $1$, and if it fall under $\frac{1}{12}$ I can decide that event occurred at this month.

But

> how can I decide if and how many events occur per month given distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a standard uniform random variable, i.e. $X\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, then to generate a uniform integer between $A$ and $B$ you can calculate $$Y= A+ \lfloor BX\rfloor$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor operator.
For instance, to pick a month randomly (with uniform distribution), you will have to set $A=1$ and $B=12$, and you will get $Y\in[1,12]$. That is, the month at which the event happens.

If the event happens $K$ times per year, then you can repeat this for $K$ times with $X_1, X_2,\cdots X_K$, and you will get $Y_1, Y_2,\cdots Y_K$. In a computer, you can do it as an array.

Comment: I like the change in approach, but it unfortunately able to produce like "one" occurrence of distribution