# Random number generation: divisibility

Tags: probability, random, programming

I'm interested in generating random numbers.

I have a distribution [for simplicity let it be uniform distribution] of some event occurrence, i.e. the event (visits to a doctor) occurs between $1$ to $3$ times **per year**.

I want to change resolution of events to be on **per month** basis. We know how to do it for one [tracked person](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918958/random-number-generation-changing-time-interval).

In case there are more than one person (e.g. I want to simulate a small town of $200,000$ inhabitants visiting my favorite clinic), this imposes a formidable difficulty, as from programming point of view, I need now to track each visitor with a dedicated PRNG.

> My interest is to obtain a **single** PRNG, which in streaming mode,
> aka the one used for a **per year** event generation, will produce
> events in the needed or extremely close distribution.

E.g., for **per year** generation, I can generate a number of visits in a loop, to asses a total number of visits per year. Each call for PRNG produces a number of visits for the next person.

Is it possible from mathematical point of view to create a single **per month** PRNG?

Comment: That's an average of 400,000 visits per year, so 33,333 per month. A normal distribution with mean = variance = 33,333 should be good enough

Comment: Do you need to know _which_ inhabitants visit the clinic that month, or do you just need the total number of visits?

Comment: I need to track specific ones

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is. The existing machinery doesn't know what a year vs. a month is. So why would switching to monthly require to track every individual ?

Comment: Turned out, this is the requirement of at least $1$ visit per person per year

Answer (score 0):

After more thoughts, it would be better to model arrivals, as a **Poisson process**, then due to [infinite divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) property we can model arrivals per month as independent $\frac{1}{12}$th of per year process. And they are all independent (we can assume this).